# Passing values from Oracle Object type parameter to PLSQL Table type parameter

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

How can we pass a parameter that is declared as an Oracle Object type to a Procedure having a parameter as PLSQL Table type?

Eg:

```
Procedure A(p_obj_emp t_obj_emp)
Procedure B(p_emp_tab t_emp_tab)
```

Where t_obj_emp = Oracle Object and t_emp_tab is a PLSQL Table of binary_integer

How can we pass a parameter that is declared as an Oracle Object type to a Procedure having a parameter as PLSQL Record type?

Eg:

```
Procedure C(p_obj_dept t_obj_dept)
Procedure D(p_dept_rec t_dept_rec)
```

Where t_obj_dept = Oracle Object having 2 fields (deptid, deptname) and t_dept_rec is declared in package specification as t_dept_rec with 2 fields (deptid, deptname).

Kindly help with some example.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles for me and appears to do what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_obj_emp AS OBJECT (
  emp_id      INTEGER,
  emp_name    VARCHAR2(100)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_obj_dept AS OBJECT (
  dept_id     INTEGER,
  dept_name   VARCHAR2(100)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg AS

  TYPE t_emp_tab IS TABLE OF t_obj_emp INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  TYPE t_dept_rec IS RECORD (
    dept_id     INTEGER,
    dept_name   VARCHAR2(100)
  );

  PROCEDURE A(p_obj_emp t_obj_emp);
  PROCEDURE B(p_emp_tab t_emp_tab);
  PROCEDURE C(p_obj_dept t_obj_dept);
  PROCEDURE D(p_dept_rec t_dept_rec);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE A(p_obj_emp t_obj_emp)
  IS
    v_emp_tab     t_emp_tab;
  BEGIN 
    v_emp_tab(1) := p_obj_emp;
    B(v_emp_tab);
  END;

  PROCEDURE B(p_emp_tab t_emp_tab) IS BEGIN NULL; END;

  PROCEDURE C(p_obj_dept t_obj_dept)
  IS
    v_dept_rec    t_dept_rec;
  BEGIN
    v_dept_rec.dept_id := p_obj_dept.dept_id;
    v_dept_rec.dept_name := p_obj_dept.dept_name;
    D(v_dept_rec);
  END;

  PROCEDURE D(p_dept_rec t_dept_rec) IS BEGIN NULL; END;
END;
/
```

Note that there isn't any 'convenient' way to create one object/record from another, even if they have identical members (such a `t_obj_dept` and `t_dept_rec` in the example above).  You must copy across the values of all the fields individually.

You say that `t_emp_tab` is a "PLSQL Table of binary_integer".  I'm guessing you mean that it's a PL/SQL Table of some type *indexed by* `binary_integer`, as it's far more common to index these tables by `binary_integer` than it is to store `binary_integer`s in them.  For the example above I've assumed that it's a table of `t_obj_emp`s.  If it's not, you'll have to map the `t_obj_emp` object to whatever type of object or record `t_emp_tab` is a table of.

Comment: Thanks Luke, suppose the  t_obj_emp = Oracle Object having an empID as a field and t_emp_tab is a PLSQL Table of binary_integer declared within package specification as type t_empId_tab is table of T_EMP Table.EMP_ID column index by binary_integer. How can I pass value from Oracle Object to this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you would need to do is change procedure `A` to store `p_obj_emp.empId` instead of `p_obj_emp`.  PS:  *Please edit your question to clarify what `t_emp_tab` (or `t_empID_tab`?) is a table of.*